# Sharepoint 2013 Configuration is hanging on Step 3 and log is filled

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, wizard, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard.  Version 15.0.4420.1017.  The wizard appears to run fine through all the setup screens.  Once it begins with step 3, I note it has created the SharePoint_AdminContent_xxx, and SharePoint_Config databases.  After an hour, I checked the event log for the SP server there is no sharepoint events, and in the SQL Server's event log, there are only login events.
I next went to the PSCDiagnostics log to find 100s of thousands of lines with the info 'Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image' (An subset of the log is below).  A few are scattered about the log.  But within a minute after Step 3 begins, this is message appears continually until I cancel the setup.
Does anyone have ideas of what my next step should be?
Steve

P.S.
The PS server is running on a VS with Windows Server 2012 6.2.9200, 2 logical cores, 8G Ram, 80G disk

The SQL Server is running on a VS with Windows Server 2012 6.2.9200, 4 logical cores, 6G Ram, a 128G(C:) and a 80G disk (for SQL data only)

SQL Server version is 11..0.3128.0

I've run the prerequisites program successfully.

The Farm Service account is in the local Administrator's Group

The SQL Service Account is registered in SQL server with sysadmin, serveradmin and secureadmin, and setupadmin roles

Token Services are configured, but installation is using NTLM currently

Anti-virus has been disabled

Configuration Wizard version 15.0.4420.1017, post latest hotfix

```
 ------------------------    Sample from the log  -----------------------
Begin trace logging for SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard.  Version 15.0.4420.1017
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Found value in collection for key disconnect
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Found parameter disconnect in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                  Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                  Entering function ConfigurationDatabaseTask.DetermineIfRepair
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key disconnect
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Found parameter disconnect in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key server
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  1  INF                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Found parameter server in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key database
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                      Found parameter database in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:55  9  INF                  Leaving function ConfigurationDatabaseTask.DetermineIfRepair
08/21/2013 15:47:55  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:55  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:55  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:55  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:55  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                  Entering function ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key initialize
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found command initialize in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key server
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter server in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter server is chosen, so returning the value as mbapmspsql01\ns
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key database
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter database in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter database is chosen, so returning the value as SharePoint_Config
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key admincontentdatabase
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter admincontentdatabase in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter admincontentdatabase is NOT chosen, so returning the default value as SharePoint_AdminContent_9736fa05-8b8c-4147-b63a-91919bfb208c
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key create
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter create in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key addomain
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter addomain in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key adorgunit
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter adorgunit in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key dbuser
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter dbuser in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter dbuser is NOT chosen, the default value as null
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key dbpassword
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter dbpassword in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter dbpassword is NOT chosen, the default value as null
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key user
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter user in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter user is chosen, so returning the value as rmt\spsqlservice2013
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key password
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter password in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter password is chosen, so returning the value as ***************
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter password is chosen, so returning the value as ***************
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Common.CreateSecureSringFrom
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Common.CreateSecureSringFrom
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key passphrase
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter passphrase in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter passphrase is chosen, so returning the value as ***************
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    The parameter passphrase is chosen, so returning the value as ***************
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Common.CreateSecureSringFrom
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Common.CreateSecureSringFrom
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Found value in collection for key skipregisterasdistributedcachehost
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Found parameter skipregisterasdistributedcachehost in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Entering function Farm.IsJoinedToFarm
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Entering function Farm.TryIsJoinedToFarm
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                            Found value in collection for key initialize
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Found command initialize in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Entering function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                            Found value in collection for key B2B_UPGRADE
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Found parameter B2B_UPGRADE in collection
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Leaving function Command.this[string key]
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        My cached Farm object is null, so will load it
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Calling SPFarm.Local and SPServer.Local to get the local farm objects
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        SPFarm.Local returned null.  This usually means that the server is not joined.  But, you can delete a server from the configdb without unjoining, which would mean that this machine still thinks it is joined.
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Trying to access the server farm connection string
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Entering function TaskCommon.TryGetWssVersion4ConnectionStringExists
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Entering function RegistryHelper.RegistryHelper
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                            The RegistryHelper has the key name as Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure\ConfigDB and the registry hive as LocalMachine
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Leaving function RegistryHelper.RegistryHelper
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 registry key Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure\ConfigDB for the connection string does not exist
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Unable to get the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 connection string
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Leaving function TaskCommon.TryGetWssVersion4ConnectionStringExists
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        DID NOT discover a v4 connection string and SPFarm.Local indicates that this machine is not joined.
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Entering function Farm.Clear
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Entering function CentralAdminServiceInstance.Reset
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                          Leaving function CentralAdminServiceInstance.Reset
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                        Leaving function Farm.Clear
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                      Leaving function Farm.TryIsJoinedToFarm
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Leaving function Farm.IsJoinedToFarm
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Creating connection string for config db SharePoint_Config server mbapmspsql01\ns
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Creating connection string for admin content db SharePoint_AdminContent_9736fa05-8b8c-4147-b63a-91919bfb208c server mbapmspsql01\ns
08/21/2013 15:47:56  9  INF                    Using NTLM for sql connection string
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
08/21/2013 15:47:56  1  INF                    Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
```

Comment: Voting to move to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to resolve this issue - after wasting a good few hours re-running SharePoint installation. What I did:

1. Disable UAC (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx)
2. Reboot server
3. Run SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard as Administrator
4. Check the log files under "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS"

"Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image" is still traced but the configuration should complete (within 20-30 minutes).

Hope that helps.

Enjoy,

Samad Khan